# Ordinal Encoding with 'unknown' Values

Tags: pandas, ordinal

Subject: Question about Ordinal Encoding with 'unknown' Values in Education Levels

Hello community,I have a dataset and I'm planning to perform ordinal encoding on certain columns, particularly on the education level column. The education levels include values like ['unknown', 'illiterate', 'basic.4y', 'basic.6y', 'basic.9y', 'high.school', 'professional.course', 'university.degree'].I'm wondering if it's feasible to apply ordinal encoding in this case, especially considering the presence of the 'unknown' value.I would appreciate any advice, insights, or recommendations on how to approach ordinal encoding in the context of education levels when dealing with unknown values.Thank you for your assistance!Best regards

I'm wondering if it's feasible to apply ordinal encoding in this case

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Editing your question according to [ask] and [mre] will likely increase chances of getting answers. Taking the [tour] is also quite informative of what kind of questions this site focuses on.